# Is there a built-in way to handle multiple files as one stream?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of files, and i need to read them each in a specific order into byte[] of a given size. This in itself is not a problem for a single file, a simple *while ((got = fs.Read(piece, 0, pieceLength)) > 0)* gets the job done perfectly fine. The last piece of the file may be smaller than desired, which is fine.

Now, there is a tricky bit: If I have multiple files, I need to have one continous stream, which means that if the last piece of a file is smaller that pieceLength, then I need to read (pieceLength-got) of the next file, and then keep on going on until the end of the last file.

So essentially, given X files, I will always read pieces that are exactly pieceLength long, except for the very last piece of the very last file, which may be smaller.

I just wonder if there is already something build in .net (3.5 SP1) that does the trick. My current approach is to create a Class that takes a list of files and then exposes a `Read(byte[] buffer, long index, long length)` function, similar to FileStream.Read(). This should be pretty straight forward because I do not have to change my calling code that reads the data, but before I reinvent the wheel I'd just like to double check that the wheel is not already built into the BCL.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything in the framework, but I'd suggest making it a bit more flexible - take an `IEnumerable<Stream>` in your constructor, and derive from `Stream` yourself. Then to get file streams you can (assuming C# 3.0) just do:

```
Stream combined = new CombinationStream(files.Select(file => File.Open(file));
```

The "ownership" part is slightly tricky here - the above would allow the combination stream to take ownership of any stream it reads from, but you *may* not want it to have to iterate through all the rest of the streams and close them all if *it's* closed prematurely.

Comment: That's actually quite a good way, I'm just not sure yet if I want to implement my own stream. Instead of an IEnumerable<Stream>, a <String> could also work, because then my CombinationStream has full control over the "inner streams". I will think about which approach suits me best.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I came up based on @jon skeet's idea.

<strike>It just implements Read which was quite sufficient for me. (but no i need help on implementing the BeginRead/EndRead method.)</strike> Here is the full code containing both sync and async - Read and BeginRead/EndRead

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/combination-stream/blob/master/src/CombinationStream-Net20/CombinationStream.cs

```
internal class CombinationStream : System.IO.Stream
{
    private readonly System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.IO.Stream> _streams;
    private int _currentStreamIndex;
    private System.IO.Stream _currentStream;
    private long _length = -1;
    private long _postion;

    public CombinationStream(System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.IO.Stream> streams)
    {
        if (streams == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("streams");
        }

        _streams = streams;
        if (streams.Count > 0)
        {
            _currentStream = streams[_currentStreamIndex++];
        }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        if (_currentStream != null)
        {
            _currentStream.Flush();
        }
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Stream is not seekable.");
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        this._length = value;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int buffPostion = offset;

        while (count > 0)
        {
            int bytesRead = _currentStream.Read(buffer, buffPostion, count);
            result += bytesRead;
            buffPostion += bytesRead;
            _postion += bytesRead;

            if (bytesRead <= count)
            {
                count -= bytesRead;
            }

            if (count > 0)
            {
                if (_currentStreamIndex >= _streams.Count)
                {
                    break;
                }

                _currentStream = _streams[_currentStreamIndex++];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            if (_length == -1)
            {
                _length = 0;
                foreach (var stream in _streams)
                {
                    _length += stream.Length;
                }
            }

            return _length;
        }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return this._postion; }
        set { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Stream is not writable");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Also available as a NuGet package

```
Install-Package CombinationStream
```