# Read multiple consecutive XML files in C#'s XmlReader

Tags: c#, xmlreader, memorystream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a built-in way to handle multiple files as one stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533881/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-handle-multiple-files-as-one-stream)

I have an extremely large amount of consecutive data split into multiple files. Using XmlDocument or LINQ are not options because **these files are huge and loading 500GB into memory is not an option**.

Therefore I ***must*** use XmlReader.

The files I have are fragmented in an XML sense, e.g.:

File 1:

```
...
<Person>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>Doe</LastName>
```

File 2:

```
  <Email>john@doe.com</Email>
</Person>
...
```

One potential solution is that I need a way to set up a stream, e.g.:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)) { ... }
```

such that the stream continually feeds the XmlReader each file consecutively. So when the stream hits the end of a file, it automatically feeds it the next file. How would I accomplish that? So that to the XmlReader, it looks like it's just iterating through one large stream, but that stream is composed of multiple consecutive files?

Thanks,

Allison

Comment: I hate to vote to close, since this is a really well-written question, but my answer would just be a copy and paste of the linked one.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to xml will eat massive xml files for breakfast.

are you aware of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx ?